# How to export the specify format

Tags: export, format

I have a such table

```
table = Table[{i, 2*i}, {i, 10}];
```

Now I want to export it as a `.txt` file. If I use `"Table"` like this

```
Export["test.txt", table, "Table"]
```

I will get a `\t` as the separator. If I use `"CSV"` like this

```
Export["test.txt", table, "CSV"]
```

I will get a `,` as the separator.

But actually I hope use a `blank space` as the separator. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Export["test.txt", table, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
```

There's also `"TextDelimiters" -> " "` that might be useful in some instances.